# How to Replace a string with the Indian Rupee's symbol

Tags: android, string, unicode

I am developing an application which needs the Indian Rupee's symbol 
my string is something like this

**result=Rs 0**
My Code to replace this string is

```
if (result.contains("Rs")) {
     result.replace("Rs","₹");
     MenuItem balance = menu.findItem(R.id.action_balance);
     SpannableString s = new SpannableString(result);
     s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, s.length(), 0);
     balance.setTitle(s);
}
```

result.replace("Rs","₹"); is a string which i had copied from net
i had done also like this

```
<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>

 result.replace("Rs",getResources().getString(R.string.RS));
```

But doesn't work anything... any other option is there than please answer it

Comment: Does your xml layout file include the `utf-8` declaration? Because it seems you miss the UTF-8 support...

Comment: Also another way is defined `String str="\u20A8";` and used it like `balance.setTitle(str);`

Comment: see this link http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm

Comment: MD read my que ..i had use this too

Comment: string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>

Comment: @Tufan Ya i did but it's perfect working in my case. I don't know why not working with you. it's strange.

Comment: Or maybe you are just replacing `"RS"` (R followed by S), not `"₨"` (\u20A8). Which is different (2 chars against only 1)

Comment: `Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Rupee.ttf");
textView1.setTypeface(tf);
textView1.setText("`");`

Comment: @DerGolem i m replacing it correctly ...

Comment: yeh fin i can do with font but i have to download forn ..this is not easiest way

Comment: No. You are replacing `"Rs"`, not `"₨"`.

Comment: what is it @DerGolem R capital nd s small ..where you find differences

Comment: The "Rs" **string** (**2** characters) is different from the Rupee symbol **character** (**1** character). For your reference: http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=rupee

Comment: I see the very same difference which is there beween `"USD"` and `"$"` or between `"GBP"` and `"£"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code is working

```
 <string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>
```

In code :

```
     MenuItem balance = menu.findItem(R.id.action_balance);
     SpannableString s = new SpannableString(result.replace("Rs",getResources().getString(R.string.RS)));
     s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, s.length(), 0);
     balance.setTitle(s);
```

OR Edit your code as :

```
if (result.contains("Rs")) {
     result = result.replace("Rs","₹");
     MenuItem balance = menu.findItem(R.id.action_balance);
     SpannableString s = new SpannableString(result);
     s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, s.length(), 0);
     balance.setTitle(s);
}
```

OR Edit your another code as :

```
<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>

 result = result.replace("Rs",getResources().getString(R.string.RS));
```

Comment: @tufan :: you have to reassign String after Replace string

Answer (score 1):

you can define String rsString = "\u20B9" and call setTitle(rsString);
Or you can use "\u20A8". It may not work on Emulator but will work on device